# How to get the limit value from the django API URL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

from the below Url, I need the limit, to do some operations in my view

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/emp/?limit=10&offset=5
```

I tried using the below things but no luck

```
 if request.limit>5:
        do something...

     if kwargs['limit'] >5:
        do something....
```

Comment: `request.GET.get('limit', '')` . To get all params as a dict, use `request.GET.dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like tushortz said in his comment this is what you should do:

```
limit = request.GET.get('limit')
if limit > 5:
    #Do something here
else:
    #Do something else
```

You could also directly compare request.GET.get('limit') with your value.

I just like to assign them to a variable, if I need it somewhere later.

Answer (score 2):

**As documented in [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/) you should use *request.GET***

to get all http Parameters as an [QueryDict object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).

You then just need to get the key 'limit' from that Object as [stated here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get).

In your example:

```
request.GET.get('limit')
```

**If you would rather have a default value than receive an error message if the key does not exist you should use:**

```
request.GET.get('limit', 'default value')
```

**Complete Code:**

```
 if request.GET.get('limit') > 5:
        #do something...
 else:
        #do other things
```